# error python: a float is required

Tags: python, math, runtime-error

I am new here, and I'm getting used to programming with Python. I have been searching through the web looking for useful answers but, it was impossible to find a solution to my problem.

Here it goes:

```
radiation=1.3888 
n=17
LAT=51.05

def dec(n):
    if 0<n<365:
        dec=23.45*math.sin(math.radians(360*(284+n)/365))
        print(dec)
    else:
        print('the day',n,'is not valid')

def wss(LAT,dec):
    wss=math.degrees(math.acos(((math.tan(math.radians(LAT)))*math.tan(math.radians(dec)))))
    print(wss)
```

--- When I run this code this is what I receive:

```
>>> dec(n)
-20.91696257447642

>>> wss(LAT,dec)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:/Users/Gerard/Dropbox/Master Thesis Gerard Pujol/Master Thesis Work/work hourly radiation OK.py", line 25, in wss
    wss=math.degrees(math.acos(-((math.tan(math.radians(LAT)))*math.tan(math.radians(dec)))))
TypeError: a float is required
```

I don't know why the Python gives me this type of error: 'a float is required'.

I have tried a lot of modifications but have been useless. I hope somebody has a solution to my problem. Thank you very much!

Comment: fix the formatting of your code

Comment: (I put the code into code blocks but it's also indented incorrectly)

Comment: It looks like you're calling `math.radians(dec)`; `dec` is a function, not a value; maybe you meant to call `dec(something)`?

Comment: another possible improvement: 360*(284+n)/365  thats int division, you should divide by 365.0 or so, since otherwise you will end up with trouble (though i think in 3.x it should work, but i am assuming you use 2.x)

Comment: fix this `def wss(LAT,dec(n)):`

Comment: @KobiK: did you actually tried your suggestion ? I guess not...

Comment: @bruno desthuilliers i missed that dec(n) has no returned value, i think that's also the problem but the fix i wrote is also needed.

Answer (score 1):

```
    radiation=1.3888

    n=17

    LAT=51.05

    def dec(n):

        if 0<n<365:

            dec=23.45*math.sin(math.radians(360*(284+n)/365))
            print (dec)
            return dec

        else:

            print('the day',n,'is not valid')
            return -1


    def wss(LAT,dec):

       wss=math.degrees(math.acos(((math.tan(math.radians(LAT)))*math.tan(math.radians(dec)))))

        print(wss)
```

Then do:

```
>>> dec = dec(n)
-20.91696257447642
>>> wss(LAT,dec)
```

---

This will work. To know why your code didn't work, read on.

What you are doing with `def wss(LAT,dec)` is that you are defining a function that passes two arguments LAT and dec. However, when you are actually calling that function (e.g. `>>>wss(LAT,dec)`) you have not set any value for `dec`. You have a value in `dec(n)` but you have not assigned it to anything. Contrast this with the variable `LAT` to which you assigned a value. (Remember `LAT=51.05`?)

Answer (score 0):

The variable `dec` is used both for a function name and a variable.  Python is seeing it as a function name in the error.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is something like

```
def dec(n):
    if 0<n<365:
        dec = 23.45*math.sin(math.radians(360*(284+n)/365))
    else:
        print('the day %d is not valid' %n)
        return
    return(dec)
```

and then call

```
wss(LAT, dec(n))
```

`dec` here is a function, so you cannot pass it as an argument. Since `dec` is returning a float, I guess that's what you actually want to retrieve.

Comment: please check your facts. Python functions are objects, and you can pass them as arguments like any other object. Also in this case `dec()` is not returning a float, it's returning `None`.

Comment: My bad, I read the question too quickly. I corrected my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much sir, it works! So thankful! I was fighting for hours without success.. I have to study more!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your formatting is terrible. Learn how the code should look like - it will save you a lot of time later on, especially while debugging.

Secondly,when you run: 
wss(LAT,dec)

You pass 2 arguments to function 'wss', first one is LAT = 51.05, but you have never defined an argument called 'dec' - you have defined such a function.

What you want to do is something like this:

```
import math

n=17
LAT=51.05

def CalcDec(n):
    if 0<n<365:
        dec=23.45*math.sin(math.radians(360*(284+n)/365))
        return dec

def CalcWss(LAT,dec):
   wss=math.degrees(math.acos(((math.tan(math.radians(LAT)))*math.tan(math.radians(dec)))))
   return wss

print CalcWss(LAT, CalcDec(n))
```

Remember to take care of possible exceptions. And read a bit about good programming practices...

Comment: Still quite confusing to use a variable called `dec` inside the `dec()` function, and why have `()`s on one of the `return`s but not the other?

Comment: Thank you very much sir, it works! So thankful! I was fighting for hours without success.. I have to study more!

Answer (score 0):

You first have to actually return something from the `dec()` function - neither assigning to a local name nor printing to stdout won't do:

```
def dec(n):
    if not  0 < n < 365:
        # that's how you handle incorrect arguments in Python
        raise ValueError("'%s' is not a valid day number" % n) 

    # 'n' is valid, let's proceed: 
    return 23.45 * math.sin(math.radians(360 * (284 + n) / 365.0))
```

Now you can use this value either thru an intermediate variable:

```
LAT = 51.5
n = dec(17)
print wss(LAT, n)
```

Or just skip the intermediate variable:

```
print wss(51.5, dec(17))
```

NB : if using Python 3.x, replace `print <something>` with  `print(<something>)`